# Can't Go Get module using default proxy

Tags: go

I was setting up go environment in a new office laptop.
I can't install any module because there's this 'authenticationrequired' problem

I have tried to empty the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variable. Still no progress

```
go get go.opentelemetry.io/otel
```

The response is:

```
go: module go.opentelemetry.io/otel: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/@v/list": authenticationrequired
```

Is there any specific setting that i should do?

here is my GO ENV:

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="arm64"
GOBIN="/Users/{office_member_id}/go/bin"
GOCACHE="/Users/{office_member_id}/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/{office_member_id}/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="arm64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/{office_member_id}/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/{office_member_id}/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.20.5"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/Users/{office_member_id}/Projects/GO/otel/go.mod"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_FFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-O2 -g"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch arm64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/rz/skq03f555yb4n4l_d67q4qx13z6_w0/T/go-build511019120=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Really appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: Maybe `proxy.golang.org` is blocked, maybe `proxy.golang.org` is resolved to an outdated IP. Try to use another mirror (for example, `go env -w GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn,direct`) or edit your `/etc/hosts` file to map `proxy.golang.org` to a correct IP.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. Turns out this error was coming from my `bash_profile` file in the macbook. I've added some custom proxy setting in it way back then when I was starting to use this laptop. I've deleted it and it works. Thankyou @ZekeLu